# How to add new fields like mobile while signup in grafana

Tags: grafana

How can I add new fields like mobile while signup in grafana? Please help
me, I want to add new mobile field to grafana and it has to store it in
a database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: sorry sir, actually while signup the grafana, we have username,password field, In that i have to add mobile field.That's my problem.Please help me out!!!